# REST fileupload in Spring controller using multipart/form-data

Tags: spring, rest, backbone.js, file-upload

Is it possible to upload file with additional data (like description etc.) with use of `multipart/form-data`? I'm using backbone.js in my frontend and I call REST api with it (jQuery).
I don't use any view resolver but I want to somehow pass my file to controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(UploadItem uploadItem, HttpSession session)
```

so that uploadItem stores:

```
private String desctiption;
private List<CommonsMultipartFile> fileData;
```

But I'm not adding (and I can't) this to my model.

Of course I'm also interested if it's possible to have controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(someFileType uploadItem, String desctiption)
```

Comment: Have a look at the mkyong tutorial for file upload with spring MVC http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/, it's with a form submit and not an ajax request but the rest should apply. Are you seeing error messages?

Comment: but it uses jsp. Is it possible to create such form html only?

Comment: Yes a normal html form or an ajax request would work too, in the end the jsp gets parsed in the server side and turned into a normal html form.

Comment: Kindly add it to the answer as to how you solved it & mark that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass the other form fields also along with multi part data. You can check the field name and use it like. (**if (item.getName().equals("desctiption"))**).

```
try {
    // Parse the request
    List items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
     FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
     if (!item.isFormField() && !item.getName().equals("")) {
      String fileName = item.getName();
      String root = context.getRealPath("/");
      File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
      if (!path.exists()) {
       boolean status = path.mkdirs();
      }

      File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
      fileNames.add(fileName);
      System.out.println("File Path:-"
        + uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());

      item.write(uploadedFile);
     }
    }
   } catch (FileUploadException e) {
    System.out.println("FileUploadException:- " + e.getMessage());
   } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception:- " + e.getMessage());
   }
  }
```